# Making my web crawler

Tags: python, web-crawler, pycharm

I'm trying to make a web crawler with a sort algorithm which shows basic idea of page rank but unfortunately it doesn't work and gives me few errors which don't make sense to me and here are those errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



File "C:/Users/Janis/Desktop/WebCrawler/Web_crawler.py", line 88, in <module>
    webpages()
  File "C:/Users/Janis/Desktop/WebCrawler/Web_crawler.py", line 17, in webpages
    get_single_item_data(href)
  File "C:/Users/Janis/Desktop/WebCrawler/Web_crawler.py", line 21, in get_single_item_data
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 65, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 49, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 447, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 378, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 303, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 360, in prepare_url
    "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '//www.hm.com/gb/logout': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:////www.hm.com/gb/logout?
```

If I change line:

```
for link in soup.findAll ('a'):
```

to:

```
, {'class':' '}
```

It works but I my task is to crawl other web pages and it that case that doesn't work.

And here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

all_links = defaultdict(int)

def webpages():

        url = 'http://www.hm.com/gb/department/HOME'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
        for link in soup.findAll ('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            print(href)
            get_single_item_data(href)
        return all_links

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = link.get('href')
        if href and href.startswith('http://www.'):
            if href:
                all_links[href] += 1
            print(href)


def sort_algorithm(list):
    for index in range(1,len(list)):
        value= list[index]
        i = index - 1
        while i>=0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value
                i=i -1
            else:
                break

vieni = ["", "viens", "divi", "tris", "cetri", "pieci",
         "sesi", "septini", "astoni", "devini"]
padsmiti = ["", "vienpadsmit", "divpadsmit", "trispadsmit", "cetrpadsmit",
         "piecpadsmit", 'sespadsmit', "septinpadsmit", "astonpadsmit", "devinpadsmit"]
desmiti = ["", "desmit", "divdesmit", "trisdesmit", "cetrdesmit",
        "piecdesmit", "sesdesmit", "septindesmit", "astondesmit", "devindesmit"]



def num_to_words(n):
    words = []
    if n == 0:
        words.append("zero")
    else:
        num_str = "{}".format(n)
        groups = (len(num_str) + 2) // 3
        num_str = num_str.zfill(groups * 3)
        for i in range(0, groups * 3, 3):
            h = int(num_str[i])
            t = int(num_str[i + 1])
            u = int(num_str[i + 2])
            print()
            print(vieni[i])
            g = groups - (i // 3 + 1)
            if h >= 1:
                words.append(vieni[h])
                words.append("hundred")
                if int(num_str) % 100:
                    words.append("and")
            if t > 1:
                words.append(desmiti[t])
                if u >= 1:
                    words.append(vieni[u])
            elif t == 1:
                if u >= 1:
                    words.append(padsmiti[u])
                else:
                    words.append(desmiti[t])
            else:
                if u >= 1:
                    words.append(vieni[u])

    return " ".join(words)

webpages()

for k, v in sorted(webpages().items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    print(k, num_to_words(v))
```

Comment: By the way that numeration is in my language so don't get confused about it. It means units =["", "one" ...] and so on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making my own web crawler in python which shows main idea of the page rank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535800/making-my-own-web-crawler-in-python-which-shows-main-idea-of-the-page-rank)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure the protocol exists in the link. For example, in the link you grabbed in the anchor tag was mostly likely schema less (there was no `http` or `https` in from of the first two `//`). This is normally used to tell the browser to use the original protocol used to retrieve the page (if you went to `http://a.foo.com`, all links specified as `//a.foo.com/bar` would use http, and vice versa if you originally reached the page via https). To solve this generally, you should test the hrefs you retrieve from the page for http or https, and add the appropriate one if it doesn't exist (you could pass in the protocol used to retrieve the original page).

As an example you could change `get_single_item_data()` to:

```
def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    if not item_url.startswith('http:'):
        item_url = 'http:' + item_url
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        href = link.get('href')
        if href and href.startswith('http://www.'):
            if href:
                all_links[href] += 1
            print(href)
```

Of course this won't solve all issues (if there aren't any `//` originally provided, if the link is actually relative to an id on the page (starts with `#`, etc). But it might be a good start - sanitization of web pages isn't fun, nor is it trivial :(. (Also note, hardcoding values is bad, as I did with `http:`, but I thought it fair since the passed in URL begins with `http`.)

Comment: you mean something like `if href and href.startswith('http'):`

Comment: Pretty much, the issue is just that the URL that you got back is protocol-relative. (which in all honestly is super nice to use from a development standpoint because then you don't need to worry about testing over http locally and then ensuring it's providing users with the correct https link)

Comment: well it didn't solve my problem, but after python gives me back all the links last thing what it prints is `//www.hm.com/gb/logout`

Comment: And also my question is, why when I crawl other web pages e.x. _http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_ it gives me back nothing?

Comment: Right, so to retrieve the links with the requests library, they need a protocol (either http or https). So you'll need to appropriately prefix them with a protocol. As to the second question, I'm a little unsure what you mean with regards to nothing? Do you mean your code gives you no links, there's not even a `//` in front of a web address, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be dont page rank and web crawl at the same time, youre just asking for trouble, when page ranking you have to consider every page youve already crawled, if you do this every time you crawl a page then the amount of times you must consider each page is going to be factorial of the number of pages crawled (!NoPagesCrawled). youre best crawling a few thousand or however many then sorting them in big go, just a thought :)